# Get non matching data from 2 array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have arrays, 1 array is master data and other array which contains pipe seperated value. please find below the code for the same

```
var master = [
{id:1, value:'John'},
{id:2, value:'Bobby'}
];

var names = [
{id:1, name:'Sandra|John', type:'user', username:'sandraJ'},
{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
{id:3, name:'Peter|John', type:'user', username:'peteJ'},
{id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'},
{id:4, name:'Peter1|John1', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];
```

The resultant output should be the following

```
var result3 = [
{id:1, name:'Sandra'},
{id:2, name:'Peter'},
{id:2, name:'Peter1|John1'}
];
```

I tried following ES6 version but it does not throw the expected output.

```
let result = names.filter(o1 => !master.some(o2 => 
o1.name.split('|').includes(o2.value)));
```

i also tried replacing some with every, but still it doesn't work

```
let result = names.filter(o1 => !master.every(o2 => 
o1.name.split('|').includes(o2.value)));
```

can someone please help me with the same?

Comment: I don't really understand your resultant data? Can you check if your example is correct and explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: where do you get the `id` from, what happens with `name`?

Comment: Please, explain what You would like to have in result array.

Comment: my resultant output should be non matching data in my array 2 
    var result3 = [
   {id:1, name:'Sandra'},
   {id:2, name:'Peter'},
   {id:2, name:'Peter1|John1'}
    ];

Comment: Wait, is the rule that if a name exists i master, any other names including that name have to be split? Hence Peter1|John1 stays, but the contractions of x|John don't?

Comment: my resultant output should be non matching data in my array 2 which are not present in my master

Comment: You can do let " result = names.filter(o1 => !master.some(o2 => 
o1.name.split('|')[0] === (o2.value)))" , but i dont get the point. Do you wish elements of master table to be "edited" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does assume that the ids in the result aren't correct, since I have no idea otherwise how Peter|John and Peter1|John1 change their id to 2.

```js
const master = [
  {id:1, value:'John'},
  {id:2, value:'Bobby'}
];
const names = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra|John', type:'user', username:'sandraJ'},
  {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter|John', type:'user', username:'peteJ'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'},
  {id:4, name:'Peter1|John1', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];
// map the valid names for easier access
const valid_names = master.map(({ value }) => value );
// We could map => filter instead if that's clearer.
const invalid_items = names.reduce(( invalid_items, item ) => {
  // Get all the diferent names inside the item.
  const item_names = item.name.split( '|' );
  // Filter out all the valid names
  const invalid_names = item_names.filter( name => !valid_names.includes( name ));
  // If there are invalid names remaining, create a new object.
  // No idea how the "id" property should be transformed.
  if ( invalid_names.length ) {
    invalid_items.push({
      id: item.id,
      name: invalid_names.join( '|' )
    });
  }
  return invalid_items;
}, [] );
console.log( invalid_items );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
const master = [
  {id:1, value:'John'},
  {id:2, value:'Bobby'}
];

const names = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra|John', type:'user', username:'sandraJ'},
  {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter|John', type:'user', username:'peteJ'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'},
  {id:4, name:'Peter1|John1', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

//This step, if you wish that the original data should not be mutated.
const namesCopy = Object.assign([], names);

//Filter through the names
const result = namesCopy.filter(obj=>{

  //Split the name if there is a |
  const split = obj.name.split("|");

  //Create a new name without the master names in it
  const newName = split.filter(name=>{
    //check to see if the master name exists within the name
    return master.findIndex(obj2=>obj2.value === name) === -1;
  }).join("|"); // Join them together as a string if there is more than one name left
  
  //If newName is empty then we can assume that master names existed in this object
  if(newName.length === 0) return false;
  
  //otherwise update the name with newName
  obj.name = newName;
  return true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this mutates the original data.

Comment: @NinaScholz is that better? Otherwise I don't know how I should go about it.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

using .map, .filter and for loop.

```js
var master = [
{id:1, value:'John'},
{id:2, value:'Bobby'}
];

var names = [
{id:1, name:'Sandra|John', type:'user', username:'sandraJ'},
{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
{id:3, name:'Peter|John', type:'user', username:'peteJ'},
{id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'},
{id:4, name:'Peter1|John1', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

let yFilter = master.map(itemY => { return itemY.value; });
let filteredX = names.filter(itemX => !yFilter.includes(itemX.name));

var processed = [];

for(var i = 0; i < filteredX.length; i++){
 var item = filteredX[i];
  var contains = master.filter(function(x){ return item.name.split("|").indexOf(x.value) > -1; });
  
  if(contains.length > 0){
   item.name = item.name.substring(0, item.name.indexOf(contains[0].value) - 1);
  }
  processed.push(item);
}

console.log(processed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the objects with the filtered names and filter then by length of the names. At the end map new objects with updated `name` property.

```js
var master = [{ id: 1, value: 'John' }, { id: 2, value: 'Bobby' }],
    names = [{ id: 1, name: 'Sandra|John', type: 'user', username: 'sandraJ' }, { id: 2, name: 'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Peter|John', type: 'user', username: 'peteJ' }, { id: 4, name: 'Bobby', type: 'user', username: 'be_bob' }, { id: 4, name: 'Peter1|John1', type: 'user', username: 'be_bob' }],
    result = names
        .map((s => o =>
            [o, o.name.split('|').filter(n => !s.has(n)).join('|')]
        )(new Set(master.map(({ value }) => value))))
        .filter(([, { length }]) => length)
        .map(([o, name]) => Object.assign({}, o, { name }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```